# How to avoid Uncaught (in promise) Error: Too many re-renders in my case

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React as the frontend and Flask as the backend.
Today, the frontend needs to use the response from the backend in the user interface, which will be stored as a `dialog` using `setDialog` and rendered in the UI.
However, an error "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop" keeps occurring.

I have tried using useEffect to fetch the dialog and also setting up a button to avoid repeated rendering, but neither method has worked.

Using useEffect:

```
const [dialog, setDialog] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const handleAddDialog = async () => {
    const url = `http://127.0.0.1:5000/question_hints_dialog/ww/dd/C1_P1`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log("data", data);
    setDialog(data);
  };
  handleAddDialog();
}, []);
```

Using button mode:

```
const handleAddDialog = async () => {
  const url  = `http://127.0.0.1:5000/question_hints_dialog/ww/dd/C1_P1`;
  const response = await fetch(url);
   dialogs = await response.json();
  
  setDialog(dialogs)
};

return(
 <Button onClick={()=>handleAddDialog()}>Start</Button>   
)
```

I would like to know how to solve this issue. Thank you.

```
<List ref = {(ref)=>setScrollbarRef(ref)} className={classes.messageArea} style={{maxHeight: 500, overflow: 'auto'}}>
            <Button onClick={()=>handleAddDialog()}>開始</Button>   
           
            {dialog && dialog.map((msg, idx) => {
              console.log("detail",msg.detail)
              let linkComponent = null;
              
              if(msg.id === 1){
                linkComponent =<></>;
              }
              else if (msg.id === 2) {

                setHintsCount(1)
                
              
                  
                linkComponent = importConcept
             
                 
                //<Link href="#" onClick={() => handleProcessStage(false, "開始 PyTutor")}>開始 PyTutor</Link>;
              } else if (msg.id === 3) {
                linkComponent = <Link href="#" onClick={() => handleConcept(false)}>GOGo</Link>;
              }
              const detail_update = <>{msg.detail}<br/>{linkComponent}</>
                
              
            
                return (
                  
                  <React.Fragment key={idx}>
               
                  <ListItem key={idx} className = {msg.from === 'student'? classes.stuPos:classes.tutorPos}>
                  {msg.detail && (
                    <Grid container className = {msg.from === 'student'?classes.stuMsg:classes.tutorMsg}>
                      <Grid item={true} xs style={{display:'flex'}}>
                      <ListItemText  primary= {
                            detail_update
                            
                          }/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item={true} xs={12}>
                        <ListItemText className={msg.from === 'student'? classes.stuPos:classes.tutorPos} secondary={currentTime}></ListItemText>
                    </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  )}
                  </ListItem>
                  </React.Fragment>
              
              
              );
            })}
            </List>
```

Here is now my frontend useEffect code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const options = await getStoredOptions();
    setOptions(options);
    setOptionsLoaded(true);
  };

  const handleScrollbar = () => {
    if (scrollbarRef) {
      new PerfectScrollbar(scrollbarRef, {
        wheelSpeed: 2,
        wheelPropagation: true,
        minScrollbarLength: 20
      });
    }
  };

  

  if (!optionsLoaded) {
    fetchData();
  }

  handleScrollbar();
  if (hint) {
    console.log("Hint updated: ", hint);
  }

  if (optionsLoaded && options?.student_name && options?.student_id) {
    console.log("initial");
    setIsNew(true);
    // do something here...
    setIsNew(false);
  }

  
}, [scrollbarRef, isSolved, optionsLoaded, hint, pesudo, cloze, originCode, advCode, count, options]);
```

Backend code:

```
@app.route('/question_hints_dialog/<string:stu_name>/<string:stu_id>/<string:hint_id>')
def generate_question_hints_dialog(stu_name, stu_id, hint_id):
    name = userInfo.student_name
    stu_id =userInfo.sudent_id

    dialog = []

    # dialog.append({"id": 1, "detail": f"... {stu_name} ... {stu_id}", "from": 'student'})

    dialog.append({"id": 1, "detail": f"...，{stu_name}！ ... " , "from": 'tutor' })
    dialog.append({"id": 2, "detail": f"...", "from": 'tutor'})
   
    dialog.append({"id": 3, "detail": "..." , "from": 'tutor' })

    dialog.append({"id": 4, "detail": "..." , "from": 'tutor' })

    dialog.append({"id": 5, "detail": "..." , "from": 'tutor' })

    dialog.append({"id": 6, "detail": "..." , "from": 'tutor' })

    dialog.append({"id": 7, "detail": "..." , "from": 'tutor' })

    dialog.append({"id": 8, "detail": "..." , "from": 'tutor' })


    return jsonify(dialog)
```

Comment: I don't know what the intention of any of this code is, but the problem isn't in the early snippets but your one "Here is now my frontend useEffect code:" near the end. This shows a `useEffect` which, amongst other things, calls `setOptions` and `setOptionsLoaded`, while having both `options` and `optionsLoaded` as dependencies. This can't help but cause an infinite rerender loop, as you're seeing.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Appreciate for your replying. I design a chrome extension chatbot and the `options` means the setting field in the options page and `optionsLoaded` use to record whether localStorage have recorded. I have tried if I remove `setDialog(data)`. The error code would disappear. But I need to save them, I can't remove them.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many method to solve this issue but they couldn't work.
Finally, I found that

```
const [dialog, setDialog] = useState<{ id: number; detail?: JSX.Element; from: string }[]>([]);
```

The problem is that  `detail` is  initialized as JSX.Element
When React reloads, it would keep to set `detail` as JSX.Element, but JSX keeps changing. So, the re-render problem happens.

Now I change to

```
const [dialog, setDialog] = useState<{ id: number; detail: string; from: string }[]>([]);
```

and it figures out.

Share here and thanks for your concern.
If anything I realize wrong, feel free to let me know.